# Marking/tagging a specific file in Mercurial?

Tags: mercurial

Is there a way to *mark* a file; not a commit or should I say, not the whole commit; but only some file within some commit in Mercurial?

Apart from the method of just writing the name of the file in the commit message, of course.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, being a change-set based VCS.

Comment: What do you exactly want to achieve with the mark?

Comment: I'm working on a simulation, and every once in a while we send the one file to a client, whose specialty is that area. That file also goes to a, uhg, ... a third party who has to approve it. Since while they're approving it (a month or two) I'm working in the meantime, and then at some point that file gets inserted back into the project, I'd just like to mark the point/revision of the file which "went out" so I know in the future. Otherwise, a month or so I don't know anymore from what commit/what file in particular (since there are several similar ones) "went out".

Comment: @favoretti - Sorry, forgot to tag you. See above.

Comment: @pst - What do you mean? How does Hg being a change-set based vcs, change anything?

Comment: @ldigas See favorettis answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Right, let's make an attempt at an answer, based on the info provided.

Mercurial is not a file-based VCS, it's change-based VCS. In other words it doesn't know that you changed fileA or fileB, all it know is that you made a changeset X. So there is, unfortunately, no way to "mark" a particular file.

As an alternative solution I'd suggest creating a "tag" ([see here](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/Tag)) on currently commited/pushed changeset when you send out a file, maybe formatting tagname to identify the file you have sent out.

Comment: Yeah, was expecting that one ... I already use tags for tagging major versions and uhm, something else. So I got (plenty) of those already. Was hoping to avoid adding another thing. But thanks, at least for the comfirmation that there ain't. If nobody comes up with a better solution, I'll acc. thi one.

Comment: @ldigas: it's a sort of perversion of course, but you could force-commit before sending out that file, then make a minor change to that particular file, and make a commit consisting solely of that file :) Crappy, but kind of solves your problem of not knowing which file of a commit you sent out :)

Comment: Meh, I think I'll stick to "LOOK HERE -> IT WAS THIS FILE" commit messages. I understood in the meantime what you ment by change based vcs, so see where the problem lies. In any case, thanks!

Comment: Cheers, glad you cleared up the "change based vcs" concept. It's important to understand what it does while working with one :)

Comment: Actually, I knew about it once (when I started with Hg), then you kinda forget all those details in everyday use and just keep in your head the five commands you use ... :)